# noun of (adjective) worth

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

Could you explain to me why this one is correct:

**He is a person of great worth.**

However, this one is not correct.

**This is cheese of fifty dollars worth.**

Their structures are identical

a person/cheese + 2 of + 3 great/fifty dollars + 4 worth

Comment: That is probably because "is a person of great worth" as a predicate of "He" makes sense but "is cheese of fifty dollars worth" if thought of as a predicate of "This" would not make any sense. i think both the sentences are fine. However, the second is a bit disturbing.

Comment: Don't know why you think the second one doesn't make sense with THIS. I can modify it for you but the problem will remain. "He gave me cheese of fifty dollars worth."

Answer (score 1):

The preposition "of" has several definitions. In "a person of great value," "of" is used to indicate the person's derivation, origin, or source ([definition 2](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/of)) or a quality that the person has ([definition 13](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/of_1)).

The same construction does not work with "fifty dollars worth" because that does not describe the source or the quality of the cheese. Instead, you are referring to an amount with a specific value ([definition 3](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/worth_2)), and that value consists of cheese in this case ([definition 7](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/of_1)).

To correct this, you would change the order of the second sentence (and change "fifty dollars" to possessive in order to use it the phrase as an adjective):

**"This is fifty dollars' worth of cheese."**

You can also use "worth" as an [adjective](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/worth_1) when coupled with a form of "to be":

**"This cheese is worth fifty dollars."**