# "serpents of red and blue"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

From "What the People Said" by Rudyard Kipling:

> Hissed up to the scornful dark
> **Great serpents, blazing, of red and blue**
> That rose and faded, and rose anew
> That the Land might wonder and mark

Is serpents of red and blue idiomatic? I am guessing it means "red great serpents and blue great serpents", but I am not sure "of" is correctly used. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is **serpents of red and blue** idiomatic?

"Serpents of red and blue" is not an idiom; poetry ignores many standard rules and (sometimes) follows its own rules. In normal writing we would use either "red-and-blue serpents" (if each serpent is both red *and* blue) or "red and blue serpents" (if each serpent is either red *or* blue).

> I am guessing it means "red great serpents and blue great serpents", but I am not sure "of" is correctly used.

While not idiomatic in this case, the usage is not incorrect. As [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/210510/130147) points out, "[noun] + of + [adjective]" is correct usage, though it can sound overly poetic or flowery in normal speech.

Also note that we would say "great red serpents and great blue serpents," following the rules of *adjective order* as extensively discussed at [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1155/421933).